# How is axis formation in the mouse embryo determined?

Tags: cell-biology, embryology

I recently came across this MCQ question when revising for stem cell biology exam.

"How is axis formation in the mouse embryo determined?"

The 5 options are as follow:
A. By sperm entry point in the egg;
B. By the first cleavage division;
C. By the node;
D. By signals from the mother;
E. By signals from extra-embryonic tissues;

The information online points toward C, but my course material seems to suggest E.

Does anyone know which one is the correct answer, and provide an explanation?

Thank you very much in advance

Comment: It would be helpful to identify/quote/cite from "the information online" versus your "course material": what are each saying, and where do you see a conflict in your understanding? Note that this website is **very uninterested** in solving your multiple choice question. That's not a very useful task outside of the very specific context of you getting a point on an exam. However, if you have a *question about understanding **biology*** and can show your work towards answering that question, we'd love to help.